# JPA entity, identify Business key

Tags: java, jpa, orm

Lets say I'm writing a JPA entity. Very simple one. It has 3 properties:

```
public class MenuItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long menuItemId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Type type;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "colorId")
    private Color color;
}
```

Now, lets say I need to override its `equals`/`hashcode` methods. According to this suggestion [Implementing equals() and hashCode()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html) I have to use some sort of "Business key equality". But I have doubts, what should I consider as a "Business" key here. Does it have to be all the properties except of `ID`, or `Color` can be excluded from it. Just seems unclear to me. Would be thankful if anyone can explain more on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

The last statement in the reference is pure gold:

> Note that a business key does not have to be as solid as a database
>   primary key candidate. Immutable or unique properties are usually good
>   candidates for a business key.

So in your case `name` and `type` would be good candidates. Assuming the Type would be an immutable object (you could still get away without that but you might experience some hard to detect bugs).

IF you would put a unique constraint on `color` then i would consider that in the `equals` / `hashCode` method also.